# Limit the number of concurrent processes spawned by incrond

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing, gnu, inotify

I'm working on developing a process that will eventually be resident on a CentOS (latest) virtual machine, I'm developing in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS...

So, I have incron set to monitor my drop folder with `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` so that when a file is written into it a rather resource intensive script is then run on the file (Images, imagemagick). this all works fine; unless too many files are dropped at once. the script, as I said, is rather resource intensive and if more than 4 or so instances run concurrently my development machine is brought to its knees (the eventual virtual machine will be beefier, but I foresee instances where perhaps HUNDREDS of files will be dropped at once!)

dangerous incrontab:

```
/path/to/dropfolder IN_CLOSE_WRITE bash /path/to/resourceintensivescript.sh $@/$#
```

so the question is: how to limit the number of jobs spawned by incrond? I tried using gnu parallel but couldn't figure out how to make that work...

for example:

```
/path/to/dropfolder IN_CLOSE_WRITE parallel --gnu -j 4 bash /path/to/resourceintensivescript.sh $@/$#
```

seems to do nothing :/

and:

```
/path/to/dropfolder IN_CLOSE_WRITE;IN_NO_LOOP bash /path/to/resourceintensivescript.sh $@/$#
```

ends up missing files :P

Ideas on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very basic way to do this is to simply use grep and count the processes... something like:

```
    processName=myprocess

    if [ $(ps -ef |grep -v grep|grep ${processName} |wc -l) -le 4 ]
    then
      do something
    fi
```

With the loop suggestion:

```
processName=myprocess

while true
do
  if [ $(ps -ef |grep -v grep|grep ${processName} |wc -l) -le 4 ]
  then
    do something
    break
  fi
  sleep 5
done
```

Comment: yup, this keeps things to a dull roar and makes the 'ol CPU and memory quite a bit happier ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sem` utility that comes with parallel:

```
/path/to/dropfolder IN_CLOSE_WRITE sem --gnu --id myjobname -j 4 /path/to/resourceintensivescript.sh $@/$#
```

Comment: for the "myjobname" section of that should I use the name of my script? does that work? or do I need to use the name of the process the script is calling eg: "convert"? my initial testing with this syntax seems to result in nothing being done... my separate logger entry for incrontab works, but the entry for calling the script with "sem" doesn't seem to launch any processes :/

Comment: myjobname is simply an id. You can use MyIdInStEaD if you want.

Comment: I think this will still generate many `parallel` (`sem`) processes while waiting for the script to finish.